# How to compile JavaMail Mbox Store on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven, jakarta-mail

I need to store locally emails downloaded via POP3 and so I'm tring to use JavaMail Mbox Store, which is part of the JavaMail source code but not compiled.

https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/MboxStore

I've followed the instructions at the end of this page, but with no luck. Here comes what the instructions says:

```
 export MACH=`uname -p`
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java
 cd mbox
 mvn
 cd native
 mvn
```

I've changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable according to my environment. I get no error until the last command. The docs says that by default these are the options used by `maven`:

```
mvn -Dcompiler.name=c89 \
     -Dcompiler.start.options='-Xa -xO2 -v -D_REENTRANT -I${env.JAVA_HOME}/include -I${env.JAVA_HOME}/include/solaris' \
     -Dlinker.name=c89 \
     -Dlinker.start.options='-G' \
     -Dlinker.end.options='-L${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/${env.MACH} -lmail -ljava -lc'
```

I've changed the compiler name to `gcc` and removed some options unrecognized by `gcc` (`-Xa` and `-x02`). Unfortunately, it complains about a missing `maillock.h`.

Do you know where I can find a complete list of dependencies? Am I doing something wrong with options? I've tried to look for any pre-compiled version, but I had no luck.

I'm trying to compile on Slackware 14.1.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu/Debian/Mint you need the liblockfile-dev package.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to compile on Ubuntu 12.04 but still it complains that the option `-G` isn't recognized by `ld` and that it can't find `-lmail` and `-ljava`. At least it compiles now, but the linker still fails.

Comment: -G tells the Solaris linker to produce a shared library; I don't know what the Linux equivalent is.  -lmail should probably be replaced by -llockfile.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Debian Whezzy I had to manually set the archecture and then add the -shared option to stop the undefined reference to main (asumming the linux equivalent to -G in Solaris). Also add the additional library path for linjvm which is under the server directory

```
export MACH=amd64
mvn -Dcompiler.name=c89 \
 -Dcompiler.start.options='-v -D_REENTRANT -I${env.JAVA_HOME}/include -I${env.JAVA_HOME}/include/linux' \
 -Dlinker.name=c89 \
 -Dlinker.start.options='-shared' \
 -Dlinker.end.options='-L${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/${env.MACH} -L${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/${env.MACH}/server -llockfile -ljava -jverify -ljvm -lc'
```